# Не понимаю логику аутентификации через JWT и Токен

Tags: jwt, аутентификация

Сразу же извиняюсь перед теми, кто не любит повторных вопросов.
Вроде бы информации много, но где то я не могу уловить суть. Именно в статьях. Возможно в книгах все есть, но читаю еще другие, времени нет.

**Не понимаю, использовать только токен, или сразу же JWT и простой токен? Или можно одним из токенов обойтись?**

Вот как я думаю, какоую роль должны играть `JWT токен` и просто `токен`:

1. Проверять `JWT токен` я думаю только тогда, когда человек переходит
   по страницам. Типа: Авторизован ли человек или нет? Алгоритм
   проверяет. Но сама подпись как я смотрел по интернету, не должна
   быть в БД.
2. А вот простой токен, типа: `Login + Password и как то зашифровать`(вроде это так, до конца не понял), он должен быть в БД.
   И использовать его только тогда, когда например оставить
   комментарий, или что то еще. Отправляются его данные на сервер и
   смеряются, если он есть в базе данных то оставить комментарий под
   тем ником, с который соответствует токен. Типа в место `id` `токен`.

Правильно ли я понимаю?

**Если правильно, то где должны храниться два токена? В Cookie?**

*Помогите пожалуйста ответить на эти **2** вопроса! Читаю вот, но до конца не могу понять, как сделать грамотною аутентификацию.*

Comment: «простой токен» должен быть строго случайным. Никаких логинов, никаких паролей, никаких шифровок. Только случайные символы.

Comment: Если у вас есть JWT, то вам простой токен не нужен. Если у вас есть простой токен, то вам не нужен JWT. Выберите что-то одно, нет никакого смысла городить два токена.

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за направления! Но как быть тогда, если человек захочет оставить комментарий? Я читал, и все говорят что не нужен JWT токен записывать в БД. Но как система определит пользователя? Я думаю по подписи, но люди пишут что её не нужно запихивать в БД. И все таки JWT токен в куки хранить?

Comment: Внутри JWT записано, какому пользователю он принадлежит

Comment: Доброго времени вам! Именно в **Payload**? Например `user_id: "jdydyf731j-ds773hhds-32ugdg13-3hdhfh"`. А его хранить в базе данных как я понял?

Comment: Нет, payload хранится внутри JWT

Comment: Это я понял. А по данным в Payload узнавать пользователя? Просто зачем мне тогда хранить там `user_id: "jdydyf731j-ds773hhds-32ugdg13-3hdhfh"`?

Comment: А не нужно в payload хранить такой мусор, просто положите туда обычный user_id:123 и потом проверяйте что пользователь 123 реально существует (хотя если вы не планируете удалять пользователей, то даже проверять не надо, вы же не будете делать JWT для несуществующих пользователей?)

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, вас понял. Но если человек просто изменит там id на цифру 122? Он же может под другого пользователя что то делать. Или все таки как я понял уже, проверять на подлинность данных через подпись а потом если данные не подделаны, то разрешать например оставлять комментарий.

Comment: Подпись не позволит изменить, да (главное - не разрешайте использовать алгоритм `none`, ибо он ничего не проверяет)

Comment: @andreymal не понял, что за алгоритм `none`?
Я просто думал, обратно расшифровывать данные и создавать новую подпись, и смерять её с той, что у пользователя.

Comment: Все уже разобрался! Я думал что Header -> "alg": "HS256" не обязательно, думал что просто для генерации подписи. Оказывается нужно проверять для начала какой алгоритм шифрования использует JWT токен.